# { x£ { 0,1 } *| ∉ { 01,10 } * } prove that it is a regular language or not

Tags: computation-theory

In my computational theory class we have an assignment of proving a language is regular. The language is defined as:

{ x£ { 0,1 } *| ∉ { 01,10 } * }

I don't know how to solve it but if someone could push me in the right direction to try and prove this is a regular language.

Comment: this is a coding question platform

Answer (score 0):

Your language is the language of all strings over {0, 1} that are not in the language `{01, 10}*`. By closure properties of regular languages, we know that the complement of a regular language is also a regular language. But your language is the complement of the regular language `(01 + 10)*` with respect to the universe `(0+1)*`. So, your language must be regular. To see this, make a DFA for the regular language (01 + 10)* and then make all non-accepting states into accepting states, and vice versa.